# Heading in plots by mvpart()?

Tags: r, cart, multivariate-regression

How can I put in a heading in the tree output when using `mvpart()`? I am using `xv="1se"`.

e.g. using the spider data in mvpart

fit<-mvpart(zora.spin~water+sand+moss+reft+twigs+herbs,data=spider)

from this I get a tree in R. And I am wondering how to "put in" a heading in this figure.

Comment: You need to explain more, with a full example; `mvpart()` is a complex function doing all sorts of things. What do you mean by "tree output"? Use the example in `?mvpart` and edit your Q to include a worked example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want the PCA plot, here's how you can add some text to the top of the plot. You can use `margin` argument in `mvpart` to add some extra space around the edges. Feel free to play around to massage the title to something of your liking.

```
fit <- mvpart(data.matrix(spider[,1:12]) ~ herbs + reft +
           moss + sand + twigs + water, spider, xv = "1se", margin = 0.1)
mtext("Mission accomplished", side = 3, cex = 2)
```

[image]